# Problems running Postgres "createuser" command

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x, command-line

I'm trying to run the `createuser` command on an MacOS 10.15 installation of Postgres 11.6. I have enabled `root` but there is no `postgres` user to `su` as - there's a `_postgres` user instead:

```
dd@finglas:~ $ cat /etc/passwd | grep 'post'
_postfix:*:27:27:Postfix Mail Server:/var/spool/postfix:/usr/bin/false
_postgres:*:216:216:PostgreSQL Server:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
```

The `$PATH` is valid for Postgres tools, and `which createuser` points to the correct binary:

```
dd@finglas:~ $ which createuser
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/createuser
```

I was expecting to be able to execute something like:

```
dd@finglas:~ createuser dev_user
```

I can login to Postgres itself as the `postgres` user, but I'm unable to run a `createuser` from the terminal. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database user defaults to the same name as your operating system user. Try to specify it explicitly:

```
createuser -U postgres dev_user
```

If that causes authentication problens, try again as operating system user `_postgres`.